# iParameterInspector array manipulation of inputs OR accessing members of an object in an array of Objects

Tags: .net, arrays

I have an array of objects (with just one element) which is sent to a function (IParameterInspector - but that is not important) , the element is an object with a string and an int.

In the function (inspector) i need to access the actual string and integer. How would i do this?

so : private object test(string operationName, object[] inputs) {

//here i need to access inputs[0]'s name and size elements

Answer (score 0):

, just some more information on the above...

the language is c#
and the function call is not "test"..
its actually:

```
private object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs) 
{
   //here i need to access inputs[0]'s name and size elements
}
```